# How many Maxwell relations are there in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, maxwell-relations

I am just learning about partial differentiation and Maxwell relations cropped up as an example. Considering that we are dealing with the 4 different variables $p$, $V$, $S$ and $T$. I would think that there would be 6 Maxwell relations because when using the Legendre transformations, there are 6 choices of two variables from these 4 for me to create a function dependent on these two variables. And I thought that this would mean there are 6 relations. Try as I might I cannot seem to find any more than the four that are given in my lecture notes.

When I looked this up, Wikipedia stated that

> ... the four most common Maxwell relations are the equalities of the second derivatives of each of the four thermodynamic potentials, with respect to their thermal natural variable (temperature $T$; or entropy $S$) and their mechanical natural variable (pressure $P$; or volume $V$)...

which seems to imply that there are more than four. However, the graph on the same [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations)

[image]

*Picture from Wikipedia.*

This makes it look like there are only 4 non-degenerate ones?

Comment: The answer to this is infinity, because you can have an arbitrary number of particle types in a gas, if nothing else, not to mention adding other state variables like a magnetic field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's funny that you have fallen in the same mistake I made when studying Maxwell relations just a few weeks ago. At first glance, it may look that the total number of Legendre transforms has to be $C^2_4$ which is equal to $6$.

However, not every combination is possible, T and S are always coupled in the same term and so are P and V. Therefore, the total number of combinations becomes $$A^2_2 \times A^2_2=4$$

Comment: What is the definition of $C_4$ and $A_2$?

Comment: @Silas In mathematics, $C$ is a symbol for combinations and $A$ is a symbol for arrangements.

Answer (score -2):

Aren't there 64 relations? At least that's what I recall from when I was doing my eng-phys undergrad at McMaster